# ubuntu 16.04 LiveCD/Intall no video output

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, 16.04

Installing Ubuntu 16.04 from USB drive on a fresh build PC with a new Nvidia GTX 1080 card.

I get the initial menu options (try Ubuntu, install etc) but after selecting Try I get a black screen (monitor reports invalid DVI signal)

I've tried selecting the `nomodeset`  option and still get the same.

Any other workarounds known ? (I know I'm in frontier territory with the 1080)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a backlight problem, you could fix it by adjusting your kernel parameters on boot time like this:
Press e when the grub menu shows up and append on the linux line:

acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor

or, if you still have problems use the legacy parameter:

acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=legacy

or finally try in combination with nomodeset:

nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/577464)

Comment: Thank you for your comment but since he mentioned that he added nomodeset, why need clarification to also add two more options on the SAME PLACE with nomodeset?

Comment: @dimk because the answers section is for answers. Please have a look at the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to see how this site works.

Comment: I think I understand now, I m sorry.

Comment: I can confirm that this solves the problem with Ubuntu and the GTX 1080 video card. In my case I used the last proposed option using nomodeset

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem having the NVIDIA GTX 1070. I could start the installation adding modeset before running it and ubuntu 16.04 is installing now. I hope that I can normally start ubuntu after the installation.