# please help fix black screen and OS failure

Tags: boot, grub2

I've been having a fairly critical issue that I've yet to resolve. It may be that I need to take this to launchpad but if ANYONE has info at all, please help. [Cannot boot OS. Black Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808807/cannot-boot-os-black-screen) explains the problem. If you have good experience with this OS or other knowledge that pertains, please take a look at that link and reply. I need help here as this is above my head. 
Thanks in advance for your time.

[listen, forget the badges for a sec and let this through. I need help here and the prior post has 0 replies and likely will stay that way.]

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. Thank you.

Comment: If the previous question has no replies, what will make you think that another one, in which you do not talk about the problem at all, will actually be better? O.ò

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. That really helped solve the problem. Ubuntu is better now as a whole I am sure.

Comment: Have a look on http://askubuntu.com/questions/785321/ubuntu-16-04-livecd-intall-no-video-output/785340#785340